# (JavaScript) How do I create a snapshot of the document so that new changes don't apply to it

Tags: javascript

I need to create constant that is set to the "document" variable that won't be affected by any changes made to the document after it is declared. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit, explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: No idea what you want to achieve.

Comment: I have a series of dividers and I need the content to be replaced the the content of the divider next to it. This works fine when the It's referencing the next divider although when it wants to reference a previous one they are all set to the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make a constant when the page loads:

```
window.onload = function() {
    const saved = document;
}
```

Then change the page back when you want:

```
function change() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = saved.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
}
```